# How to make a cookie in Django (Python)

Tags: jquery, python, django

When I use this application (Filedownload, jquery)
https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

There are some important issue in order for this plugin to work you must also write a cookie in an http header "Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/"

How can I make a cookie in Django framework? (fileDownload, path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Cookies, how can I set them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/django-cookies-how-can-i-set-them)

Comment: Did you look in the documentation, where this is well explained?