# Materialize modal pops up when returning to Home page from another site page

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm using Materialize's modal for an email sign-up pop-up on load, and the issue I'm running into is that when I first visit the site the modal pops up as expected.  But if I click on another page, like go to the About page, and then back to the Home page, the modal launches again.  How can I get it to only pop up the first time the page is visited?  Any advice is much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Want more of 'Carrow?</h4>
            <p>Join our mailing list!</p>
            <p>No, we won't fill your inbox every day, and no, we won't sell your information to anyone else – PROMISE!</p>
            <p>What you will get is content only available to our email subscribers, as well as advance notice on upcoming events and book launch dates.</p>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#modal2" class="modal-action modal-close button">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal2" class="modal"
    style="height:350px;">
        <form class="container"
        style="padding:45px;">
            <label>Name:  <input type="text" style="border-color:#840081;" autofocus /></label>
            <label>Email: <input type="email" style="border-color:#840081;" /></label>
        </form>
        <div class="row center-align">
        <!-- <div class="modal-footer"> -->
            <a href="" class="modal-action modal-close button" id="join-btn">Join!</a>
        </div>
    </div>



<script>
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let wavePosX = e.offsetX,
            wavePosY = e.offsetY,
            button = e.target,
            buttonWidth = button.clientWidth,
            wave = document.createElement('span');

        wave.className = 'material-wave';
        wave.style.top = wavePosY + 'px';
        wave.style.left = wavePosX + 'px';

        // Append wave element to the button
        e.target.appendChild(wave);

        // Start scale and opacity transitions
        setTimeout(function() {
          wave.style.opacity = 0;
          wave.style.transform = 'scale(' + buttonWidth / 10 + ')';
        }, 0);

        // Remove the wave element after the transition
        // Should use Modernizr's transitionEndEventName
        setTimeout(function() {
          button.removeChild(wave);
        }, 800);
      });
    };
</script>

<script>
    $('.modal').modal({
        dismissible: true,
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 200
      }
    );
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#modal1').modal('open');
    });
    $('#join-btn').click(() => {
        $('#modal1').modal('close');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what are you using server side? You'll need to either have access to the referrer (If coming from about page don't show). Or you need to use session variables. You can even set a cookie with an expiry date. So it won't bother for sign up for the next two weeks.

Comment: If you're looking for an html/js solution you can send a parameter from your other links and evaluate whether or not to throw popup modal. Let me know if I should show you how to do this.

Comment: Hi thanks so much!  I'm using Django Rest Framework for collecting the email addresses.  If you could point me in the right direction as far as setting up a expiry cookie that would be awesome!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/django-cookies-how-can-i-set-them, perhaps use this link as a starting point. I don't work in django myself - but update your question and someone who does can find it and help you!

Comment: @alirk are you still stuck at this problem?