# Django admin :: I want to keep last selected value on adding another item

Tags: django

Context

1. in django administration site
2. I am adding a new item in a model via *add* button
3. when the form is displayed, I have a **dropDown**  with some options to choose, I choose option B and I fill other fields to complete the form
4. I click on button *save and add another*

When the new "add form view" is displayed 
I want my **dropdown** to set on the last choice (B option) I selected before

What is your suggestion to implement that as simple is possible?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you tell me if the drop down is a ChoiceField or ManyToManyField.... or what

Comment: Hi,
It's a ForeignKey

Comment: An idea is to [use a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/django-cookies-how-can-i-set-them/5575578#5575578) and hold the necessary data there in order to retrieve it when the next from instance appears.

Comment: i can help you if you create the objects from your own site not the admin if you can.., tell me and i will help you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer the following solution:

1. Create author (fk auth.User) and created (datetime auto_now_add=True) fields in your model.
2. Override get_form function in model admin class, get the last object created by the current user in it and put the required initial value in the foreign key field

Code examples (not tested, it's just an idea):

```
# yourapp/models.py
from django.db import models

class ModelOne(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    model_one = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

# yourapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from yourapp.models import ModelTwo

@admin.register(ModelTwo)
class ModelTwoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ModelTwoAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if '_addanother' in request.POST:
            latest_object = ModelTwo.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('created')

            form.base_fields['model_one'].initial = latest_object.model_one
        return form
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot devxplorer,
after tried your code and did some tests, I got this solution works for me :

```
#app/admin.py
def get_changeform_initial_data(self,request):
    latest_object = ModelTwo.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('created')
    return {'model_one': latest_object.model_one_id}
```