# How to set cookies by using Django?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        email_input = str(request.POST['email'])
        password_input = str(request.POST['password'])
        user_Qset = Profile.objects.filter(email = email_input)

        if user_Qset is not None:
            password_saved = str(user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password'])
            if password_input == password_saved:
                request.session['name'] = str(user_Qset.values('name')[0]   ['name'])
                request.session['email'] = str(user_Qset.values('email')[0]['email'])
                request.session['password'] = str(user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password'])
                return HttpResponse('login success.')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('locin failed, wrong password')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('login failed, wrong email address')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

I want to add cookies by using `request.session` method but it doesn't work

How can I use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Cookies, how can I set them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622793/django-cookies-how-can-i-set-them)

Comment: Try `response.set_cookie`

Comment: You're using the session, not cookies. But why do you need to use cookies specifically? The session is usually preferable.

Comment: I'm beginner in Django. so, I've practiced to use cookies and session. Now I know how to set and get cookies and now I'm search how to use session

Answer (score 1):

1. Differences

As you may know, there is a **huge difference between cookies & session**.
**Cookies store data on the client side**.
Sessions use a cookie as a key, and associate it with the data that **is stored on the server side**.

2. Sessions are better

It is usually **better to use sessions instead of cookies** because the data are hidden from the client, and you can easily set when the data expires to become invalid.

3. Security reasons

**On the security side**, if it was all built around cookies, a vicious user could change their cookies data send bad request to your website.

---

But if you want really use cookies, Django now handle direct cookie manipulation methods on the request and response objects.

You can do so as follow :

**Views.py**

```
def signin(request):
    response = HttpResponse('login success.')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        email_input = str(request.POST['email'])
        password_input = str(request.POST['password'])
        user_Qset = Profile.objects.filter(email = email_input)

        if user_Qset is not None:
            password_saved = str(user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password'])
            if password_input == password_saved:
                response.set_cookie('name', str(user_Qset.values('name')[0]   ['name']))
                response.set_cookie('email', str(user_Qset.values('email')[0]['email']))
                response.set_cookie('password', str(user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password']))
                return response
            else:
                return HttpResponse('locin failed, wrong password')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('login failed, wrong email address')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**Sources**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/