# how to save data from telegram session - django

Tags: python, django, session, telegram, twitch

I have a telegram bot that sends a link to let the user authentificate with twitch, obviously when twitch send a response only gives me information about the twitch user that logged in, how can i get information like who is the telegram user that clicked the link?
I asked a similar question [here](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/how-to-save-data-during-authentification/32772/3) but now i realize that i didn't understand what to do (anyway probabily the answer i received is more useful to you).

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def telegramBot(request): #function that handles telegram messages
    return telegramBotFunction(request) #return a http response

#the user is redirected here after login with twitch, how can i get the telegram id?
def verify(request):
    return gestioneVerificaAuth(request) #return HttpResponse("<h2> Twitch user is subscribed/or not to streamer X <h2>)
```

Edit: Updated the code

Comment: You can use request cookies to store the value. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623910/3612571

Comment: Really helpful but can't understand how to do it, at wich response should i set the cookie? And where i could get the cookie?

Comment: if necessary i can post the rest of the code but i keep modifying it